# Xcode build taking very long time in github actions

Tags: xcode, react-native, github-actions, devops

I've written an iOS build pipeline in GitHub Actions.
But the `xcodebuild` (`Build iOS (debug)`) step is taking approximately 25 minutes to finish. Is there any way to reduce the build time?

Here's the workflow:

```yaml
name: iOS

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: 14.x
        
    - run: npm ci

    - run: xcode-select -p
    
    - run: pod install
      working-directory: ios
      name: Install pod dependencies

    - name: Build iOS (debug)
      run: "xcodebuild -workspace ios/AwesomeProject.xcworkspace -scheme AwesomeProject clean archive -sdk iphoneos -configuration Debug -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -archivePath $PWD/AwesomeProject CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO"

    - name: Compress .xcarchive
      run: zip -r -9 AwesomeProject.xcarchive.zip $PWD/AwesomeProject.xcarchive/

    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: ios-xarchive
        path: AwesomeProject.xcarchive.zip
```

Comment: How long does it take on your local setup?

Comment: Also, as you're using a GHA-hosted macOS runner, you might want to compare the specs of your local setup with what [GHA-hosted macOS runner has](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#supported-runners-and-hardware-resources).

Answer (score 0):

You can use self-hosted runners, cache dependencies, and cache build folders.

Remember that GitHub Runners always start from scratch if you don't do any caching.